# Recommendations MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) Bootcamp 120 GB

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, sd-card

I'm considering installing bootcamp to play a single game *Valorant* on my Macbook. I'm clearing up storage space for this very purpose, and will have only 80 GB of free storage space to likely even partition when done.

For this reason I am considering using a SanDisk Extreme Storage (256GB) Micro SD to partition for bootcamp.

If I am only running a single game, what is reasonable amount of storage to run a game like Valorant, and would using an SD be necessary/ more efficient?

Comment: The Boot Camp Assistant along with the Windows Installer GUI probably will not allow you to install Windows on a Micro SD.

Answer (score 1):

Windows won't take more than 32 GB and Valorant is only 4 GB, it's probably best to install everything on Bootcamp. You could do a speed comparison by copying your Riot Games folder to the SD.